# What is `hooker script` actually in `scripts/init-top/all_generic_ide`?

Tags: ubuntu, initrd

I'm studying `init` in Ubuntu's ramdisk.
In `scripts/init-bottom/udev` I saw this code snippets:

```
PREREQ=""
prereqs()
{
    echo "$PREREQ"
}
case $1 in
# get pre-requisites
prereqs)
    prereqs
    exit 0
    ;;
esac
```

It appears almost every scripts in `scripts/**` scripts(like `scripts/init-top/all_generic_ide,scripts/local-bottom/ntfs_3g,scripts/local-premount/fixrtc`,etc). Although they may have some subtle differences, but most of them are just have same snippets on the top of body code.

I read the wiki from Ubuntu: [initramfs-tools](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/initramfs-tools.8.html)

I totally have no idea what its purpose. I think I can realize its flow but just can't figure out what it gonna do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This boilerplate code just prints the value of `PREREQ` when the script is called with the parameter `prereqs` and then exits with zero.

The man page of [initramfs-tools](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/initramfs-tools.8.html) says in HOOK SCRIPTS -> Boot scripts:

> No guarantees are made as to the order in which the different scripts are executed unless the prereqs are setup in the script.

So the scripts in `scripts/init-bottom` will be executed in an arbitrary order on boot (if they do not specify prereqs). If these script depend on each other,  the scripts have to define prereqs to ensure the correct execution order.

For example, one scripts might mounts /home (call it `mount_home`) and one script creates new user accounts (call it `create_users`). Then the second script needs to declare the dependency on the first one (calling `create_user prereqs` should return `mount_home`) by using changing the boilerplate code:

```
PREREQ="mount_home"
prereqs()
{
    echo "$PREREQ"
}
case $1 in
# get pre-requisites
prereqs)
    prereqs
    exit 0
    ;;
esac
```

If your script does not depend on other scripts inside the same directory, you can just copy the boilerplate code.